# Java7 Reserving and Assigning random positions

Tags: java, arrays, random, variable-assignment

I am making a basic color guessing game (my firstone) where you get a hex code and you'll get some color alternatives to chose from. However, I've run into some problems. The way I have it set up is that I create some ovals to which I assign random colors (one with the correct one) and that is working all fine.

The problem is that in order for the answer not to be put at the same spot every time I'm trying to randomly generate positions for these ovals, but my code doesn't work. The code (which I thought would reserve spots and assign spots) doesn't reserve spots correctly. I thought it would only go into the else statement if the positions wasn't taken `(takenPos[tempRandomNum] == false)` but it seems that it always goes into the else statement, even if my print confirms that it generated the same spot multiple times.

Another problem is that if it enters the If statement (which it doesn't right now), generates a new value, and that value is taken it uses the value anyway.

Print:

`ELSE false 0
ELSE false 540
ELSE false 0
ELSE false 360
ELSE false 360
ELSE false 450
ELSE false 180
ELSE false 360
ELSE false 540`

Code:

```
public int randomOvalPos() {
    //An array of booleans to keep track of if the position is taken.
    boolean[] takenPos = new boolean[difficulty];
    //Temporary variable to return if it gets through the if statement.
    int tempRandomNum = randomNum(0 , difficulty - 1);
    //Check if the position is taken (set before return).
    if(takenPos[tempRandomNum]){
        //If the position is taken I want it to get a new random position.
        //The problem is that if this spot is taken as 
        //well I can't just keep redoing it.
        tempRandomNum = randomNum(0, difficulty - 1);
        takenPos[tempRandomNum] = true;
        return tempRandomNum * 90;
    }else{
        //If it isn't taken set the boolean to true and return the value.
        takenPos[tempRandomNum] = true;
        return tempRandomNum * 90;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: Side note: in Java you should rarely use arrays. Your primary choice shoud be `List` unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't apparent, but this is my first game and I'm pretty new to Java so I don't know how to use those. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Raliks I hope my linked duplicate answers your question.

Comment: @durron597, I do not really understand. Should I assign the values one by one and then shuffle them around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do (before displaying the ovals to the user) is use the code that currently works and places the answer in the same spot every time, and then shuffle the array using a [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Read this question for an implementation on how to do that: [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: Okay, thank you! I am eager to learn though, could what I've made work somehow?

Comment: @Raliks I don't really understand what you were trying to do with your algorithm, sorry :-/